# Trouble understanding how RStudio Jobs is behaving

Tags: r, rstudio

The Local Job feature in RStudio is not behaving as I expect.

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
Fun1 <- function(x) x^2

Fun2 <- function(x) x^3

Fun3 <- function(x) x^4

Funs <- c('Fun1', 'Fun2', 'Fun3')

print(Fun1(2))
print(Fun2(Fun1(2)))
print(Fun3(Fun2(Fun1(2))))

print('Fun1')
print(get(Funs[1]))
print('Fun2')
print(get(Funs[2]))
print('Fun3')
print(get(Funs[3]))

print('All Funs')
print(lapply(Funs, get))
```

It works exactly as expected if the script is run with `source('myscript.r')` or the Source button in RStudio.

Using the Run Script as Local Job feature (without a copy of global environment) results in this output and error:

```
[1] 4
[1] 64
[1] 16777216
[1] "Fun1"
function(x) x^2
<environment: 0x0000000004530b38>
[1] "Fun2"
function(x) x^3
<environment: 0x0000000004530b38>
[1] "Fun3"
function(x) x^4
<environment: 0x0000000004530b38>
[1] "All Funs"
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Fun1' not found
Calls: sourceWithProgress -> eval -> eval -> print -> lapply -> FUN
Execution halted
```

The output shows objects `Fun1`, `Fun2`, and `Fun3` are defined in the job environment. Why are they not found when running `lapply`?

RStudio Version 1.4.861

R 4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `get()` isn't looking in the right environment anymore because you are bypassing the global environment. Instead use

The better function to use here would be `mget`

```
print(mget(Funs))
```

But if you want to use `get`, then you would either need to pass the environment,

```
print(lapply(Funs, get, envir=environment()))
```

or capture the environment in an enclosure

```
print(lapply(Funs, function(x) get(x)))
```

So you capture the local environment where the job is running.

You don't really need to test this using the Run as Local Job with RStudio. You can also replicate the behavior by just running in a new empty environment. A condensed example would be.

```
evalq({
  Fun1 <- function(x) x^2
  Funs <- "Fun1"
  
  print('All Funs')
  # print(lapply(Funs, get))
  print(mget(Funs))
}, new.env())
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains why the problem is occurring. In my use case I'm passing names of the functions I create in the main script as arguments to Package::Function. It works fine when I source the script, but running as a Job causes this issue - probably because a call to `get` in Package::Function. Looks like using Job feature isn't an option unless I modify Package::Function.